# Update procedure with case - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, case, isnull

i would like to request help with an update procedure. I want to update either the CPF field only or the Surname field only, currently, i can only update both together. Is there any way to do this using CASE ISNULL? Or even if you have some other way that is more clean code. I tried multiple ways but i don't do it

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_altera_pessoa (@Nome VARCHAR(15), @Sobrenome VARCHAR(15) = NULL, @CPF CHAR(11) = NULL)
AS
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SET @Command = '
UPDATE Pessoa
SET '
\+ CASE ISNULL(@Sobrenome, '')
WHEN '' THEN ''
ELSE 'Sobrenome_p = @Sobrenome'
END
\+
'
WHERE Nome_p = @Nome
UPDATE Pessoa
SET '
\+ CASE ISNULL(@CPF, '')
WHEN '' THEN ''
ELSE 'CPF = @CPF'
END
\+
'
WHERE Nome_p = @Nome
'
PRINT @Command
EXEC sp_executesql 
                @Command,
                N'@Nome VARCHAR(15), @Sobrenome VARCHAR(15) = NULL, @CPF CHAR(11) = NULL',
                @Nome, @Sobrenome, @CPF
        IF @@ERROR = 0
            COMMIT
END
END CATCH
```

Comment: Aside from having two completely separate update statements wrapped in if statements, have you considered [coalesce()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql)? e.g.: `UPDATE Pessoa SET Sobrenome_p=COALESCE(@Sobrenome, Sobrenome_p) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do one or the other I would do it like this

```
 IF @Sobrenome IS NOT NULL 
 BEGIN
   UPDATE Pessoa
   SET Sobrenome_p = @Sobrenome
   WHERE Nome_p = @Nome
 END 

 IF @CPF IS NOT NULL 
 BEGIN
   UPDATE Pessoa
   SET Nome_p = @CPF 
   WHERE Nome_p = @Nome
 END
```

NOTE: If this data is coming from a web site and might be vulnerable to injection attack do this:

```
 IF @Sobrenome IS NOT NULL 
 BEGIN
   EXEC sp_executesql 'UPDATE Pessoa 
   SET Sobrenome_p = @Sobrenome
   WHERE Nome_p = @Nome', 
   N'@Nome VARCHAR(15), @Sobrenome VARCHAR(15)', @Nome, @Sobrenome
 END
```

Also both the try catch and the transaction are not used correctly -- in a try catch you need this format:

```
BEGIN TRY  
  { sql_statement | statement_block }  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
 [ { sql_statement | statement_block } ]  
END CATCH
```

For the transaction you need a rollback if you don't commit

Comment: Thank you so much Hogan. I dont post the try catch code because exceeded limit of lines of code. The code with COALESCE works fine, but if I don't declare the CPF, the update makes the clause null, can i add an IF to fix it?

Comment: @LucasCésar -- I don't understand -- "declare the CPF" -- you mean if you don't pass the parameter to the parameterized query?  Why would you do that that -- it does not make sense.

Comment: I dont know how explain that, but CPF is like a SSN, i wanted a single query to update only the surname for example, or sometimes only the SSN, is that possible?

Comment: I see... then outside of the update statement @LucasCésar

Comment: @LucasCésar see updates

Comment: Thank you so much Hogan, u are amazing

Comment: You're welcome -- I hope your project goes well @LucasCésar